# Is it any way to add more that one OpenLayers.DynamicMeasure?

Tags: openlayers-2, polygon, ext-js

I would like to make a feature to my webapp, which I could show sum of two(or more) Polygons..
But...
When Im drawing another polygon, earlier one disappeared, when I change

```
this.layer.addFeatures([this.polygon, this.point], {silent: true});
```

to

```
this.layer.addFeatures([this.polygon], {silent: true});
```

I can add only two, when Im drawing the third one, the first one did I draw disappearing...

when Im adding the second one, dynamicmeasure to first one is disappearing...

Someone has any idea to do that?

Would like to look something like that:

[image]